# Login script with ob_start and Session, refreshing without loggin

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a problem with my login script: 
I have this 3 scripts

**index.php**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include ('config.php');
include ('home.php');
ob_end_flush();
```

**home.php**

```
 if($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
 echo $_SESSION['nome']; 
 } else { ?>
 <form name="login" action="checklogin.php";> 
 ...
 <?php } ?>
```

**checklogin.php**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
...
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
header("Location: http://$root");
die();
}
ob_end_flush();
```

My problem is this: When I try to log for the first time my page refresh without show the session. **Why??** If a try to close and re-open my browser or log for the second time it will show the session. Why? What should I do?

Comment: No I skip the part of loggin and the form, but I don't think the problem is there...I can post it in any case..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that your PHP session is still active due to the lifespan of the session cookie from PHP. See [this discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes) for ways to expire your sessions using a $_SESSION variable to hold a timestamp and then checking that timestamp to see if a certain amount of time has past.

Alternatively, that same discussion also gives detailed information on modifying the PHP server to set the default session lifespan using the garbage collection and cookie lifetime settings.

Comment: I tried to set a session timeout but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem. Are you having trouble logging in properly or is the problem that even with a session timeout you always stay logged in?

Comment: I have trouble loggin in properly, I think the problem is the header but don't know why